# Android: Internal storage image deleted at random

Tags: android, google-play

My app downloads a small number of thumbnail-sized images and stores them in internal storage (in MODE_PRIVATE). These images are loaded into a ListView at runtime. There is no code in the app that deletes these images, the only way would be by uninstalling or clearing the app data.

The problem is that, seemingly at random, at least one of the images seems to disappear from internal storage. It's very difficult to reproduce, it can happen a few hours after last running the app or it can take days.

I am wondering if there might be some internal process that runs that would be deleting internal data for some reason. Both devices I have tested and experienced the bug on have plenty of internal storage space left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by the Millenial Media SDK. It was a bug that was fixed in the latest version of their SDK.

http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-SDK/AndroidSDKReleaseNotes.html